# How can i use javascript variable in jstl tag

Tags: javascript, jstl

i am working in Spring MVC. i have no idea to use javascript variable in jstl tag.
my function,

```
function funcAlert(){
        var alert1 = document.querySelector('input[name = "deliverystatus"]:checked').value;
        alert(alert1);
    }
```

for the jstl tag,

```
<c:url var="selectDeliveryman" value="/admin/order/selectDeliveryman?id=${orderAttribute.orderId}&deliveryname=" />
```

i want to use variable alert1 in the end of deliveryname=
anyone please help me, alot of thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use as `${alert1}`, but you need to declare it globally in the script and make sure that jstl runs as sever side so you can only gain value of `alert1` which is initialize during page load after that you make any change to that variable you can not get it in jstl.

Answer (score 0):

```
<c:url var="selectDeliveryman" value="/admin/order/selectDeliveryman?id=${orderAttribute.orderId}&deliveryname=" />

<script>
function submit() {
   var alert1 = document.querySelector('input[name = "deliverystatus"]:checked').value;
   document.location="${selectDeliveryman}"+alert1;
}
</script>
```